# ENCONTRAR CLIENTES SIN PEDIDOS

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Quisiera que me ayuden con un problema sencillo q no estaria pudiendo resolver, en el ej me pide q haga un select de los CLIENTES q no tengan un PEDIDO echo, quisiera saber como es q tengo q poner para q me aparezca el unico cliente q no tiene pedidos. (son 10 clientes de los cuales el nro 10 no tiene pedidos, y son 10 pedidos en total) Dejo un par de capturas ahora para q entiendan mas...

[image: DISEÑO DE LA BASE]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste y edita tu pregunta en base a [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay diferentes formas de hacerlo, la más simple es con el operador `not in`. Seleccionamos todos los clientes que no tengan (id_cliente) un registro en la tabla pedidos

```
SELECT *
FROM clientes
WHERE id_cliente not in (SELECT id_cliente from pedidos);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la solución :)